# Do I need through an authorization first for using Imgur API?

Tags: javascript, api, oauth-2.0, imgur, fetch-api

I am totally new to API's and especially Imgur API, examples on the website may be clear to an experienced guy. I feel like there are gaping holes that I need to fill in but I am not clear. I am doing this:

```
let form = document.querySelector("#img-form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get the file data.
    let f = form.querySelector("[name=\"file\"]").files[0];

    let fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsDataURL(f);
    fr.addEventListener("load", () => {
        post(fr.result);
    }); 
});



let post = function(data) {
    // Create a new request.
    let request =
        new Request(
            'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                body: {
                    image: data
                },
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            })      
        });

    fetch(request)
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status == 200) console.log(res.json());
            else throw new Error('Something wrong with API');
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.error(err)
        });
}
```

Everything looks fine except the api says **401 (Unauthorized)**, I am too dumb for this stuff, is there some kind of authentication that goes on before the upload? Can some one help me send me a link of some step by step tutorial.

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2)?

Comment: Yeah I did, but I couldn't understand it well.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe that you tried hard enough. You wouldn't be asking if you need to authenticate after reading several pages of documentation that's all about how to authenticate to use the API.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try harder

Answer (score 2):

You are missing Auth headers

```
'Authorization': 'Client-ID YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
```

For upload images anonymously you need register you application  [Imgur OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: it still says 401 bro, I registered and got client id and client secret, it says I can upload images being anon and I selected image API without call back url FYI.

Comment: Try this here [imgur uploader](http://jsfiddle.net/nullandv0id/FGxGg/) I create this type of account: "Anonymous usage without user authorization"

Comment: Hey bro, sorry for all the trouble bro, anonymous uploading is disabled in out country. Thanks a lot I will workaround another way